# How can I fail-over my website domain?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, web-server, web-hosting, failover

I have two web servers running on a different location with different static IP:

WebServer 1: x.x.x.x
Webserver 2: z.z.z.z

Both servers should point to test.com domain. Let assume currently, Master web server is up & running and DNS Record A pointing towards static IP x.x.x.x.

Now in case of the master server goes down how can I transfer users via test.com domain to secondary webserver IP z.z.z.z?

I tried contacting DNS registry they only have nameserver backup facility example. ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com. They do not support monitoring of HTTP Port 80 in which they can transfer Record Type A to my secondary web server IP for domain test.com

Is there any way I can redirect the user to my secondary server with the same domain test.com without manually changing IP?

My web server is running on apache on ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have resolved the issue by creating a one dedicated cloud server running HAProxy. Below is the simple configuration I have used.

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # See: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&server-version=2.0.3&config=intermediate
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY>        ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets

 defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option http-server-close
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend ft_app
    bind 0.0.0.0:80 name app
    default_backend bk_app

backend bk_app
    server s1 x.x.x.x:80 check
    server s2 z.z.z.z:80 check backup
```

Comment: you could use already implemented solutions like Cloudflare Load Balancing with pools or aws route53, if you don't want to use own tool, you could create vm on a create cloud provider that check if your site is down and change the ip in the zone to the active ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you prepare an environment for redundancy, you should create some scenarious for which you want to protect your environment. Also you should have a budget as time and money for what you need to do.

You can use an http load balancer (reverse proxy) like haproxy, varnish...
You can use a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) if you have more traffic.

More complex solutions involving [BGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol#Load_balancing) and an [AS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) can be created if you need and have money.

Comment: Will ha-proxy works on a different subnet or public IP? As I can implement ha proxy if situated on the same subnet but in this scenario it's different.

Comment: It will work, but it might not be the fastest solution. Depends on the latency between haproxy and your webservers.

Comment: But you can test this easily without affecting current websites.

Comment: I am still confused how can DNS Record A will change for user to visit via ha-proxy? As this is a physical server residing in a small office and not in the cloud. Even if I configure HAproxy to monitor each other how will it work? If there is any link will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: DNS record will always point to HAProxy, which will then forward traffic to whichever server is available.

Comment: I am giving a try today.